# CMD skips a line in batch file for no apparent reason, so what's the reason?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Simply script, probably a simple question:

```
set /p customsettings="Some input prompt: "
if /i %customsettings:~0,1% equ Y echo Some output
```

^-This works fine...

```
set custom=1
if %custom% equ 1 (
    set /p customsettings="Some input prompt: "
    echo Some output
)
```

^-...and this works fine.
So why doesn't this work fine?:

```
set custom=1
if %custom% equ 1 (
    set /p customsettings="Some input prompt: "
    if /i %customsettings:~0,1% equ Y echo Some output
)
```

The `set /p customsettings` line get skipped only when it is pinched between two if-statements.

I'm curious why this happens, and how to fix it.

Note: The problem still persists regardless of `EnableDelayedExpansion`'s setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read a lot about delayed expansion on this site.  An entire IF/FOR construct (or multiple lines within parens) are loaded and expanded as 1 line.  So you have to consider LOAD-TIME behavior and RUN-TIME behavior.  Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set custom=1
if %custom% equ 1 (
    set /p customsettings="Some input prompt: "
    if /i "!customsettings:~0,1!"=="Y" echo Some output
)
```

Comment: No, sir. As I said, it happens regardless of whether EDE is enabled or disabled.

Comment: Did you make the other changes?  Copy all lines?  Works for me.

Comment: Need to use ! instead of % to expand customsettings variable at run time.  Also need to be careful with the spaces in your comparison.

Comment: Huh. Well - I noticed just now that you surrounded the conditions with quotations... Oddly enough, this makes it work with the code I pasted in the question. (works with ! and %). What would be a reason a lack of quotes causes this problem?

Comment: It is a string compare.  With the quotes you are defining the 2 strings to compare.  Without the quotes everything on the line after the if /i is the first string and there is no second string to compare to.

Comment: @RGuggisberg, thank you, I've learnt something new about batch files! I've initially posted an incorrect answer here which I shamefully had to delete. Now I understand: the batch processor treats the whole outer `if` as one command and expands the variables only once for it, thus EDE is required.

Comment: YW.  I saw the banner come up while I was answering and actually quit.  Then I realized there was no answer and continued :)  Don't feel bad... there are a LOT of questins on this site about this topic.